# Avatar Upload Issue

Tags: php, mysql

I'm scratching my head, because I can't figure out what's wrong with my code below.. $avatar_path is not saved into mysql table..

```
<?php

$avatar_path = $mysqli->real_escape_string('images/'.$_FILES['avatar']['name']);

    //check if the file type is image
    if (preg_match("!image!",$_FILES['avatar']['type'])) {

        //copy image to images/ folder 
        if (copy($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'], $avatar_path)){

            //set session variables to display on welcome page
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['avatar'] = $avatar_path;

            //insert user data into database

            $update_row = $mysqli->query("UPDATE user_data SET avatar='$avatar_path' WHERE user_id='1'") or die($mysqli->error());

        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Answer (score -1):

Could you try this ?

```
$update_row = $mysqli->query("UPDATE user_data SET avatar='$avatar_path' WHERE user_id=1") or die($mysqli->error());
```

(i.e. suppress the quotes around the id value)*
Quotes are not necessary around integers and could possibly mess it up by making mysql take it for a string.

Comment: The same! I belive that mysqli query is not the issue, because I tried code below and its worked:  `$update_row = $mysqli->query("UPDATE user_data SET avatar='bla bla bla' WHERE user_id=1") or die($mysqli->error()); `

Comment: Hmmm.... did you try to echo $avatar_path? Also, did you check that you indeed enter the 'if' control loop? (by putting a echo 'hello' somewhere). At least that could perhaps pinpoint the issue so we know what to look for